# Cómo sacar la cantidad de filas de un Jtable al ser seleccionadas

Tags: java, eclipse

Quisiera saber como sacar la cantidad de filas de un jtable al ser seleccionadas y cuando se quite la seleccion se disminuye, osea tengo tres filas y selecciono dos y la cantidad que estan seleccionadas se muestra en un JTextField y si le quito la seleccion a una fila se disminuye la cantidad.
He estado intentando con el metodo MouseClicked del jtable pero me muestra la cantidad de filas:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tbDocTransferir2.getModel();
        int filas = model.getRowCount();
        txtCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(filas));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega un [`javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) al [`javax.swing.ListSelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) de tu [`javax.swing.JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html). Es decir:

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        ListSelectionModel sm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = sm.getMinSelectionIndex(); i <= sm.getMaxSelectionIndex(); i++) {
            sum += sm.isSelectedIndex(i) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
});
```

Para saber más, véase [*How to Write a List Selection Listener*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html).

Answer (score 0):

//Recomendación

y si pruebas con un botón? aprovechas de controlarlo.

```
private void btnEliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
     DefaultTableModel miTableModel = (DefaultTableModel) miTabla.getModel();
     int indFil = miTabla.getSelectedRow();
     if (indFil >= 0)
          txtCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(filas);
          miTableModel.removeRow(indFil);
}
```

De hecho mi profesor siempre me decía *"coloquen botones , ya que cuando el usuario no sabe, va a tratar de botar tu aplicación"*

Saludos.

Comment: el objetivo es que al momento de seleccionar cada fila se vaya contando en una caja de texto cuantas filas estoy seleccionando

Answer (score 0):

```
private void jTable1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    jTextField1.setText(""+jTable1.getSelectedRowCount());
    if(jTable1.getSelectedRowCount()==0){
        jTextField1.setText("");
    }
}                                                                     

private void jTable1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    jTextField1.setText(""+jTable1.getSelectedRowCount());
    if(jTable1.getSelectedRowCount()==0){
        jTextField1.setText("");
    }
}
```

puedes usar esos eventos para la tabla y facilita las cosas